# Printing JSON Data from Python Script to PHP Site

Tags: php, python, json

I wasn't exactly sure what to title this question as I can't find much documentation on exactly what I'm doing. Apologies if this is a duplicate as I feel it combines issues a lot of other questions posed, but I couldn't get a solution working.

I have a Python script that calls an API and gives JSON data in the body of the return. I want to take this JSON data and print it to a webpage (for now, I will be pulling specific items out of it later) so that I can see that it's working.

Right now, the python script ends as follows:

```
r = requests.get(url=URL, params=PARAMS)
print (r.json())
```

PHP takes the data as follows

```
    $returned = shell_exec("python3 /var/www/eaton/BackEnd/GenerateCall.py ${arguments here}");
    $recipe = explode(',', $returned);

    echo "<html>";
    echo "<head>";
    echo "</head>";
    echo "<body>";
    echo "<pre>";

    echo $returned."<br>";
    echo json_encode((json_decode($returned)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo "</pre>";
    echo "<br>";
    echo "</body>";
    echo "</html>";
```

My output on the page is just "null". I had the text of the JSON data printing at one point (without the explode, decode, and encode methods) but it was just a string and couldn't have values extracted from it.

What is the easiest way to get this data imported in JSON format and get it to print the whole array? Running the python script from the shell seems to output the data properly, so I believe the issue is in PHP.

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is when there is no `$returned` output. If the `$returned` variable is a json string just output it and set the content type header. You don't need `html` tags if you're working with apis.

```
$returned = shell_exec("python3 /var/www/eaton/BackEnd/GenerateCall.py ${arguments here}");
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $returned;
exit;
```